# Jmeter - Conditional execution

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0, beanshell

I have a Jmeter script in which one of the sampler response contains json values as following:
4 JSON result sets containing values of
contractid, amount, status, type

The contract ids and their amounts are dynamic in nature. Im trying to figureout a solution where the condition should be  if costAmount equals 677666.00 then it should capture its associated contract id and pass that contract id in the subsequent request.

Am completely new to jmeter and this is my first script. I checked with multiple options like using a bean-shell post processor, using loop along with if controller but everytime i end up with not executing the if controller.

Can someone explain with a working solution. Appreciate any inputs on this

Tried beanshell post processor code
Loop controller with if controller
Still no luck. No matter what conditional statements never execute. Not sure where am i doing wrong

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Your questions about code, i.e. debugging questions like these, are served by not only providing the error message or problem statment, but also the code itself, a [mre]. We are not clairvoyant, so we cannot help you to debug code you do not show us. Also showing what you have already tried to solve the problem is appreciated. [Edit] the question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Conditional execution is possible, for example you can use:

1. [JSON Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) which provides the way to use [filter operators](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath?tab=readme-ov-file#filter-operators) to conditionally extract values:

   [image]
2. [If Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-if-controller) where you can check the value of `contractid` [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html). If Controller's children will only be executed if `contractid` value has been extracted in the previous step:

   [image]